# Stored procedure only show 1 row per relationcode

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure which should only show 1 row per relationcode with the latest bookingdate. Now i got this currently:

```
USE [fms]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLoadNonBooking] (@DateFrom as DATE, @DateTill as DATE)
AS

BEGIN
    WITH NonBooking (Relationcode, Companyname, LatestBooking, LatestContact)
    AS
    (
        SELECT r.[RELATIONCODE], r.[COMPANYNAME], b.[BOOKINGDATE], c.[DATE]
        FROM [fms].[dbo].[Relation] r
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[Booking] b
        ON b.[RELATIONCODE] = r.[RELATIONCODE]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[Communication] c
        ON c.[RELATIONCODE] = r.[RELATIONCODE]
        WHERE b.[BOOKINGDATE] < DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()) AND b.[BOOKINGDATE] > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY r.[RELATIONCODE], r.[COMPANYNAME], b.[BOOKINGDATE], c.[DATE]
    )
    SELECT Relationcode, Companyname, LatestBooking, LatestContact FROM NonBooking
END
```

But that currently shows me the data like this:

[image]

So it shows a line for every booking that is made, but i want 1 line for every relationcode with the LATEST bookingdate, but I am not sure how to do this, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Row_Number()` & `Top 1 with ties`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties Relationcode,
                       Companyname,
                       LatestBooking,
                       LatestContact
FROM   NonBooking
ORDER  BY Row_number() OVER(partition BY relationcode ORDER BY LatestBooking DESC)
```

If `RELATIONCODE` is unique in `Relation` table then here is one way using `Outer Apply`. Better approach in my opinion

```
SELECT r.[RELATIONCODE],
       r.[COMPANYNAME],
       oa.[BOOKINGDATE],
       oa.[DATE]
FROM   [fms].[dbo].[Relation] r
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 b.[BOOKINGDATE],
                                 c.[DATE]
                    FROM   [fms].[dbo].[Booking] b
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[Communication] c
                                        ON c.[RELATIONCODE] = r.[RELATIONCODE]
                    WHERE  b.[BOOKINGDATE] < Dateadd(month, -2, Getdate())
                           AND b.[BOOKINGDATE] > Dateadd(year, -1, Getdate())
                           AND b.[RELATIONCODE] = r.[RELATIONCODE]
                    ORDER  BY b.[BOOKINGDATE] DESC) oa
```

Comment: This won't work because BOOKINGDATE cant be selected here because it isn't accesible from there, it gives me this: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spLoadNonBooking, Line 29
The multi-part identifier "BOOKINGDATE" could not be bound.

Comment: @ThimoFranken - yeah updated we should use `LatestBooking` instead

Comment: Also, i need it to only show results for the relations where there is a booking at all. how to handle this?

Comment: @ThimoFranken - Sorry I didnt get this part *where there is a booking at all* Can you add sample data and expected result in question or new question

Comment: Nevermind, that part works now, i have now got a different problem, the result is not completely correct, it says the last booking by KUBO01 is on 03-11-2016 https://gyazo.com/e11f462ef64e2f916d8ec755b12099e3
But the actual last booking is https://gyazo.com/762b8e9e99772aa89178550a8252079f
Any idea why it does this?

Comment: hope you can help?